# Using comboBox/TextBox To output a certain number

Tags: c#

I am new here, Anyways I wanted to do the following: So lets say I have 1000 different numbers (Lets just say 1-1000) and in the comboBox or Text box I wanted to select/type in stackoverflow to get number 265 or stackoverflow 1 to get number 266 how would I do this?

Thanks for looking,

Joker

Comment: Would you be using a DB? This is a great link to get you started:
http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/cs-combobox.htm

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you could share your code, it will be easy to suggest a solution.

Comment: I have tried using a string, But in reality I have 8000 numbers and I don't think that is a very clean way to do what I need done